# Celery task chain seems to only run first task. How does the Celery chain works?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I have an issue which I believe relates to how this method works. I am creating a chain of lets say 300 pretty big tasks with a lot of items to be processed by each task. I create and async run a Celery task of this events like so:

```
result = chain(*my_tasks).apply_async(ignore_result=True)
```

so sometimes it seems to work and all the tasks are executed. But sometimes especially when I have a lot of big tasks to execute, I see in my logs that the first task run and then nothing. The tasks disappear.

I was reading in the docs that the `chain()` wraps all the individual tasks under one task. How does that work exactly? I am also using RabbitMQ as message broker.

The times that the chain works, I see in my queue a single message appearing and disappearing. As if there is always just on message in the queue and it is picked up and then another one is put there. Is this what Celery does? Or does the first worker who picks up the task form the RabbitMQ queue executes all the tasks inside one after the other?

If the second case is true could that initial worker just fail and then the message disappears? Any clarification on how this chain method works and/or what might be the problem are both greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

I am guessing `my_tasks` is a list of tasks, not list of signatures as it should be for any Celery Canvas element to work as expected.

Basically can't help you without more information (more specifically - how is the `my_tasks` list created)...

[Documentation about chains](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#chains) is very clear and everything you really need is there. Example from the abovementioned page:

```
from celery import chain
from proj.tasks import add, mul

# (4 + 4) * 8 * 10
res = chain(add.s(4, 4), mul.s(8), mul.s(10))
# proj.tasks.add(4, 4) | proj.tasks.mul(8) | proj.tasks.mul(10)
```

It shows exactly how to create a chain with 3 tasks. Notice the usage of signatures there.

Finally, the document clearly states that if any task in the chain fails, the rest of the chain will not get executed. So, it could be perhaps that what is happening there. It also states that if you have task_ignore_result set to True in Celery configuration it will not work.

> Or does the first worker who picks up the task form the RabbitMQ queue executes all the tasks inside one after the other?

Depending on the size of the chain one worker *may* prefetch them all and execute, but this is is highly unlikely, unless the tasks that are in the chain are created with *dedicated* queue (a queue only that particular celery worker is subsribed to) specified. Again, we can only guess this because the details how `my_tasks` list is created are hidden...